# Python based search engine or Elastic Search

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, search, whoosh

In our project, we want to incorporate a search engine like ES/Solr for various use cases.   Our backend stack is Python/Django.
ES has a Java dependency.
Is it advisable to use more popular and robust search engines like Elastic Search/Solr or use a native one like Whoosh or any other (suggestions welcome)

Comment: What you mean by ES has a java dependancy?

Comment: To install ElasticSearch is to just download it and run the executable. You must make sure that you are using Java 7 or greater.

Comment: you not required to install Java. Elastic come with bundle JDK.